# Cannot Check Current Activity from DrawerLayout Item

Tags: java, android

I have a navigation drawer, and if a user clicks on the navigation drawer item he will return to the home screen.

However, if the home screen is already active, I do not want to create a duplicate activity with an intent. I am essentially trying to check if the activity is already active / in the backstack, as I do not want to utilize resources inefficiently.

```
 mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            switch (i){
                case 0:
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"CLICKED 0",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Log.v("DRAWER", "THE DRAWER HAS BEEN CLICKED");
                    if (getCallingActivity() == HomeActivity){
                        onBackPressed();
                    } else {
                        Intent I = new Intent();
                    }
                    break;
```

Comment: Hi tccpg288 ! You can check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

**get current Activity**

```
// get current activity
public static Activity getCurrentActivity() {
    try {
        Class activityThreadClass = Class.forName("android.app.ActivityThread");
        Object activityThread = activityThreadClass.getMethod("currentActivityThread").invoke(
                null);
        Field activitiesField = activityThreadClass.getDeclaredField("mActivities");
        activitiesField.setAccessible(true);
        Map activities = (Map) activitiesField.get(activityThread);
        for (Object activityRecord : activities.values()) {
            Class activityRecordClass = activityRecord.getClass();
            Field pausedField = activityRecordClass.getDeclaredField("paused");
            pausedField.setAccessible(true);
            if (!pausedField.getBoolean(activityRecord)) {
                Field activityField = activityRecordClass.getDeclaredField("activity");
                activityField.setAccessible(true);
                Activity activity = (Activity) activityField.get(activityRecord);
                return activity;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Then

**change your code to this**

```
if (getCurrentActivity() instanceof HomeActivity) {
     onBackPressed();
} else {
     Intent I = new Intent();
}
```